# How do I split a list into nested list by keyword?

Tags: python, string, list

Original list is:

```
list = ['WBS1','WBS2','WAY1','WAY3','WBR1']
keyword1 = 'WBS'
keyword2 = 'WAY'
keyword3 = 'WBR'
```

Output nested list should be:

```
nested_list = [['WBS1','WBS2'],['WAY1','WAY2'],['WBR1']]
```

Comment: A side note: stay away from using `list` as a variable name, because it's a reserved keyword and sometimes has side effects you might not want.

Comment: Expanding on @monsieuralfonse64's comment: It's not just `list`. Do not name your variables and functions the same as Python's built-in data types, functions

Answer (score 3):

I'd start with putting all the keywords in a list, and then use a list comprehension to grab all the words that start with every keyword:

```py
lst = ['WBS1','WBS2','WAY1','WAY3','WBR1']
keywords = ['WBS', 'WAY', 'WBR']
nested_list = [[w for w in lst if w.startswith(k)] for k in keywords]
```

Comment: Upvoted. Only thing is, what if the keyword was in a longer string, not at the front? That `startswith()` could be changed to `in`

Comment: @monsieuralfonse64 according to the OP's example, the keyword always seems to come at the beginning of the word. If that assumption is incorrect, using `in`, like you suggested would be the right way to go